# Drag GameObject With Mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having some issues with creating a script that once the player clicks upon a gameObject that gameObject will follow the mouse. The object will be dropped once the mouse is clicked again.

Here is the script:

```
public float distance = 10;

public void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, distance);
    Vector3 objPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);

    transform.position = objPosition;
}
```

This works fine, but the issue is if the player (the main cam) has any sort of movement script upon it such as this Character controller script on it or its parent, then the gameObject that is picked up will move around as if it is trying to get away from the mouse.

```
public float speed = 6.0f;
public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
public float gravity = 20.0f;
private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

void Update()
{
    CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        speed = 15.0f;
    }else
    {
        speed = 6.0f;
    }

    if(controller.isGrounded)
    {
        moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);

        moveDirection *= speed;
    }

    if(Input.GetButton("Jump"))
    {
        moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
    }

    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

    float rotateRight = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");

    transform.Rotate(0, rotateRight, 0);
}
```

If the above script is disabled, then the GameObject does not freak out and it works fine.

I know that the input being made in the character controller is effecting the top script in some way, the mouse moving so the gameObject transforms in that direction while trying to keep to a certain point on the mouse.

But how to I make so it won't effect it.

Comment: Try placing a boolean in your update that gets toggle on drag `if(isBeingDragged) return;` . Effectively disabling the script whenever it is true.

Answer (score 0):

I bet the mouse dragging is happening before your movement.

Try putting your dragging logic in `LateUpdate()` so it can accommidate for the new position